# uwsgi version 2.0.22- fails with [strict-mode] unknown config directive: hook-as-emperor-before-vassal

Tags: hook, uwsgi

I am using uwsgi version 2.0.22 which is the latest stable version.
But the directive `hook-as-emperor-before-vassal`  is not working and gives the below error on load.
`[strict-mode] unknown config directive: hook-as-emperor-before-vassal`

As per documentation  [here](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#hook-as-emperor-before-vassal) it should be available.
I tried uwsgi --help and it doesn't show the directive listed as well.

Details:
Uwsgi being run in emperor mode.
Uwsgi built using the command `python uwsgiconfig.py --build`
Python version 3.6
OS : Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

To the curious , I was planning to use this hook to run a command to check memory utilization of the uwsgi server and spawn a vassal if memory is available also kill any vassal unused for sometime.

Anyone else face such an issue where a directive is not available. Is it to do with the build process or the environment. Any advice would be helpful.

Things tried:
Rebuilt uWSGI.

Sample config.ini file.
Uwsgi ran using command `./uwsgi -d --ini /sampleproject/config.ini`

```
# should be a directory to find .ini files
emperor = %dvassals
threads=8
socket = %demperor.sock
chmod = 666
enable-threads = true
strict = true
auto-procname = true
procname-prefix = "emperor "
route-uri = ^(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$ uwsgi:%dvassals/$2.sock,0,0
# .ini.socket files would be searched in vassals directory, this file should contain path to the socket
emperor-on-demand-extension = .socket

hook-as-emperor-before-vassal = /sampleproject/startNewVassal.py
```